# How to insert an end div inside a PHP foreach loop when count meets a specific value

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have a page that lists a set of questions and answers that are held on a database. Because these pages will be printed off on to A4, the questions and answers must fit within the page. However, because of the way the system is used, the answers are quite lengthy and over run a set dimension for an A4 piece of paper.

I have worked out that for my specific need, each A4 piece of paper will have a word limit of 680. The test data I am using has exceeded this, and currently stands are 972 words in total.

Currently this is the code I am using (be aware that there is an individual word count recorded for every individual answer and every individual question):

```
<div class="page" style="page-break-before: always;">
    <div class="smallheading">
        <h2>Management Information</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content v2">
        <?php 
        $totalCharacters = 0;
        $totalcharacters1 = 0;
        $totalcharacters2 = 0;

        foreach($sqsi as $si) {
            $totalcharacters1 += $si['Swmpquestion']['wordcount'] + $si['Swmpanswer']['wordcount'];
        } foreach ($sqsicust as $wr) {
            $totalcharacters2 += $wr['Swmpanswer']['wordcount'] + $wr['Swmpanswer']['cqwordcount'];
        } 

        $totalCharacters = $totalcharacters1 + $totalcharacters2;           

        ?>

        <?php foreach($sqsi as $si) { ?>
            <p><strong><?php echo $si['Swmpquestion']['question']; ?></strong></p>
            <p><?php echo $si['Swmpanswer']['answer']; ?></p>
            <hr />
        <?php } foreach($sqsicust as $wr) { ?>
            <p><strong><?php echo $wr['Swmpanswer']['custquestion']; ?></strong></p>
            <p><?php echo $si['Swmpanswer']['answer']; ?></p>
            <hr />
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

What I want to achieve is that while the PHP script goes through it's foreach, every time the questions and answers in that foreach reach 680 words an end and start div would be inserted, so the long list of data would be split up properly. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, then you just need to assign the variable to be iterated and make a comparison against it in your loop.

```
foreach($sqsi as $i => $si) { // note $i => 
        if($i == 679) echo '</div><div>'; ?>
        <p><strong><?php echo $si['Swmpquestion']['question']; ?></strong></p>
        <p><?php echo $si['Swmpanswer']['answer']; ?></p>
        <hr />
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you're already keeping a count of words, so why not just use a simple if statement in the second 2 foreach loops? Instead of counting the words in the first two foreach loops like you're doing.  Keep track of how many words in the 2nd two foreach loops and then a simple if statement will do the trick.  Something like this should work if I understood you correctly:

```
<div class="page" style="page-break-before: always;">
<div class="smallheading">
    <h2>Management Information</h2>
</div>
<div class="content v2">
    <?php 
    $totalCharacters = 0;
    $totalcharacters1 = 0;
    $totalcharacters2 = 0;

    foreach($sqsi as $si) {
        $totalcharacters1 += $si['Swmpquestion']['wordcount'] + $si['Swmpanswer']   ['wordcount'];
    } foreach ($sqsicust as $wr) {
        $totalcharacters2 += $wr['Swmpanswer']['wordcount'] + $wr['Swmpanswer']['cqwordcount'];
    } 

    $totalCharacters = $totalcharacters1 + $totalcharacters2;           

    ?>

    <?php foreach($sqsi as $si) { 
$totalcharacters1 = $si['Swmpquestion']['wordcount'] + $si['Swmpanswer']  ['wordcount']
if($totalcharacters1 == 680){
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class="content v2">";
$totalcharacters1=0;
}
?>
        <p><strong><?php echo $si['Swmpquestion']['question']; ?></strong></p>
        <p><?php echo $si['Swmpanswer']['answer']; ?></p>
        <hr />
    <?php } foreach($sqsicust as $wr) {
$totalcharacters2 += $wr['Swmpanswer']['wordcount'] + $wr['Swmpanswer']['cqwordcount'];
if($totalcharacters2 == 680){
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class="content v2">";
$totalcharacters2=0;
} 
?>
        <p><strong><?php echo $wr['Swmpanswer']['custquestion']; ?></strong></p>
        <p><?php echo $si['Swmpanswer']['answer']; ?></p>
        <hr />
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add an $i=0; //a starting point
and an $qtyToLpThru=x; //ie every 25 iterations
before the foreach.
within foreach add just after the first { an if statement..

```
foreach(){
  if (is_int($i/$qtyToLpThru)) && $i!=0) {
    echo '</div><div>';
  }
  $i++;
}
```

then add an `$i++;` just before the last }.

your iteration will increment the `$i` and you'll write your end and open div every time the if statement processes true.